# Audio clip not playing after collision

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, audio-source

I have been facing an audio issue for 3days. I was looking to play audio after the collision.
Not getting any proper idea OR where the problem occurs in my scenario, I could not solve my problem.
In my GameObject, I added Audio Source through 'Add Component' where I put my mp3 file into AudioClip and also
checked off 'Play On Awake'.

NB : PlayExplosionAnimation() and Destroy() are working fine.

```
public class Player : MonoBehaviour
{

    private AudioSource source;

    void Start()
    {
        source = GetComponent<AudioSource>();
    }

    void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
    {
        if (collision.gameObject.tag == "Rocks")
        {
            source.Play();
            PlayExplosionAnimation();
            Destroy(gameObject);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: You're instantly destroying your object, hence your audioSource.

Comment: Delay destroy by specifing time, e.g. `Destroy(gameObject, 0.5)`

Comment: thanks a lot @Johnny and Jichael. after put some delay it's playing

Comment: @M.S.T I will add an answer for the sake of the completeness.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the `AudioSource` is attached to the game object which has been destroyed immediately after the collision is detected so you never actually hear the sound. One potential solution could be to delay destroying of the game object by specifying how many seconds you want to delay the destroying, e.g. delay for 0.5 second.

```
void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
{
    if (collision.gameObject.tag == "Rocks")
    {
        source.Play();
        PlayExplosionAnimation();
        Destroy(gameObject, 0.5);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this out and if it still doesnt work it means there is something wrong with your audio :)

```
public class Player : MonoBehaviour
{
private AudioSource source;

void Start()
{
    source = GetComponent<AudioSource>();
}

void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
{
    if (collision.gameObject.tag == "Rocks")
    {
        source.Play();
        PlayExplosionAnimation();
        gameObject.SetActive("false");
        Destroy(gameObject, 1f);
    }
}
```

}